# Updating dropdown lists to Telerik

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a form with few drop-down lists, something like this:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Student Number
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="StudentNumber" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Student Type
                </th>
                <td>
                    <select id="StudentType">
                        <option value="Select">Select</option>
                        <option value="Freshman">Freshman</option>
                        <option value="Sophomore">Sophomore</option>
                        <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
                        <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
                <td>
                    <select id="Status">
                        <option value="Select">Select</option>
                        <option value="Enrolled">Enrolled</option>
                        <option value="Dropped">Dropped</option>
                        <option value="Probation">Probation</option>
                        <option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

I want to convert the HTML dropdown-lists to telerik dropdown-lists. What entails in converting a control to Telerik? 
This is my first time with Telerik. Any examples would be very helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use static data like you have in your question, you can do this:

```
@(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
  .Name("StudentType")
  .Items(items =>
    {
      items.Add().Text("Select").Value("Select");
      items.Add().Text("Freshman").Value("Freshman");
      items.Add().Text("Sophmore").Value("Sophmore");
      items.Add().Text("Junior").Value("Junior");
      items.Add().Text("Senior").Value("Senior");
    })
)
```

For a demo using dynamic data, see [Telerik's combobox/dropdown demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/combobox).

Comment: I get the following error:
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'Telerik' and no extension method 'Telerik' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Before you can use Telerik MVC, you need to add the dll to your project, update your web.config, and add js and css files. For a detailed explanation of everything you need to do to get started, see http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/getting-started-using-telerik-extensions-for-asp.net-mvc-in-your-project.html.